# Need help for UMA in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Unity editor's ScreenShot]

[image: Blender file screenshot]

I'm working on the avtar customiztaion for a game using UMA2 package.
I wanted to add my own clothes and accesories to the character, by watching this tutorial- https://youtu.be/7wklwssOWB4.
I have done all the steps according to the video but still can't achieved the output.
I don't know why the glasses are get rotated.

here's the FBX file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DGlcoO7s63_dJ_9HmI7Nsu7hPBt845Fl/view?usp=sharing

1. When i export the fbx with default scale applied, i wasn't able to see glasses or pants on the character.
2. After scaling it to 100 units in blender, i have found that the glasses is on the face. But it's rotated by 90, even though i have applied all transforms to the objects.

Comment: hm not sure how that UMA package works .. just threw this FBX into Unity and with the default generated avatar it looks correct to me ... https://imgur.com/O6MU9I0